# Entity Framework Error - The version of SQL Server in use does not support datatype 'datetime2'

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I am using Entity Framework 4.0 in an ASP.NET 4.0 Web Form.

All is fine on the development server. But when I get to the production server, I my Elmah logs this error

> System.ArgumentException
>   The version of SQL Server in use does not support
>   datatype 'datetime2'.

I did a quick research and found out that `datetime2` aka `datetime2(7)` is the problem and setting `ProviderManifestToken="2005"` will solve the issue.

My problem is this. My Development Server has **SQL Server 2008 R2** and Production Server has **SQL Server 2008 Express**. So, changing the manifest to 2005 doesn't seem right.

My questions are

1. Will setting `ProviderManifestToken="2005"` work?
2. Why has Entity Framework generated a `datetime2` when I haven't used it at all in any of the table?
3. Is there a better work around?

Comment: Although being a duplicate of your question, this [other question](/q/10224406/1178314) as attracted more attention and answers and may be worth checking.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I dont see any workaround till date. So if you are using **SQL Server 2008 Express**, please right click on your edmx, open it with XML (Text) Editor and set `ProviderManifestToken="2005"`.

Doesn't sound that good. But its all I have got as of now.

Comment: Just run into this issue a second time. Setting gets overwritten on an model update. Maybe we can "solve" this with post build-actions.

Answer (score 2):

I found that the answer in this blog post worked for me: [The version of SQL Server in use does not support datatype 'datetime2'](http://weblogs.asp.net/kencox/archive/2010/11/15/fix-the-version-of-sql-server-in-use-does-not-support-datatype-datetime2.aspx)

> It turns out that Entity Framework 4 somehow got the idea to use  SQL Server 2008. The fix was to edit the .edmx file in an XML editor and set the ProviderManifestToken="2005" instead of 2008. (You need to rebuild.) Here’s how the line should look against SQL Server 2005:

```
<Schema Namespace="OfficeBookDBModel.Store"
    Alias="Self" Provider="System.Data.SqlClient"
    ProviderManifestToken="2005"
    xmlns:store=http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/12/edm/EntityStoreSchemaGenerator
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/02/edm/ssdl">
```

Comment: That works for me as well but if you have to update your model it will reset it to 2008 if that is what you are using to do development. You will then need to change it again before you push your code out onto your test or prod box.

Answer (score 0):

Just put `DateTime.Now` as the date if you have no other...

Had the same error and this solved it because if you dont set a value for your date time object it will be 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM...this give you the error then... again this is how i solved the problem

Comment: i am already doing that. plus that error will be unable to convert datetime2 to datetime right?