# the version of sql server in use does not support datatype 'datetime2'

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008, entity-framework, sql-server-2005

My development server is MS SQL Server 2008 and visual studio 2012. The project works fine when i run it on local but when i try to run the same project on server then it gave this error and doesn't allow to Insert or update date.
ERROR:
       "The version of sql server in use does not support datatype 'datetime2'."

My online server is using the MS Sql Server 2005.
I am not using any field with the data type "datetime2" all fields have data type datetime.
Secondly i also tried by changing field from ProviderManifestToken=”2008” to ProviderManifestToken=”2005” but it doesn't effect.

Comment: Do you have any functions, types or stored procedures that use `DATETIME2`?

Comment: None of stored procedure using this data type.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to use DATETIME2 in your database to get this error.see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10224406/the-version-of-sql-server-in-use-does-not-support-datatype)

> This error happens usually once you add required (NOT NULL) DATETIME
>   column to existing table and you don't set the value prior to saving
>   the entity to database. In such case .NET will send default value
>   which is 1.1.0001 and this value doesn't fit into DATETIME range. This
>   (or something similar) will be source of your problem.

Comment: I am on using DateTime.Now; to set the datetime for current record.

Comment: Please dont share this link

Comment: Oh Thanks Shahrooz Jefri i will not do this again.