# ASP.NET Datetime2 Issue on Server

Tags: asp.net

In my ASP.NET application, everything works as expected when running it locally but when I publish the server I get the following error:

```
"The version of SQL Server in use does not support datatype 'datetime2'."
```

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10224406/the-version-of-sql-server-in-use-does-not-support-datatype-datetime2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
If you are using Entity Framework model in your project.
Then open entity model in html or xml mode. and change ProviderManifestToken="2008"
to ProviderManifestToken="2005". after that publish on server then check and let me know.
```

Comment: Great to see the question asking guy name is "Sehta Umesh" and the answer giver name is "Umesh Sehta"!

Answer (score 1):

According to this article, SQL server 2008+ supports datetime2. I am assuming your server does not run SQL 2008+ but your local SQL Express does.

[Difference between datetime and datetime2](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/06/11/sql-server-difference-between-datetime-and-datetime2/)