# SQL server version error (datetime2)

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf

At my client machine application throwing below error. seems like error is related to sql server.

Application is developed in VS 2010, WPF.

> *The version of SQL Server in use does not support datatype 'datetime2'*

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Which SQL Server version you are using? Looks like `datetime2` type only available in SQL Server 2008 and 2012.

Comment: "seems like error is related to sql server." - yeah. It is not like it is not telling you that EXACTLY.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using Entity framework and sql server then actually issue is in Entity framework.

you have to make some changes in entity framework.

check below link would be helpful.

[Entity Framework Error - The version of SQL Server in use does not support datatype 'datetime2'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6547051/entity-framework-error-the-version-of-sql-server-in-use-does-not-support-datat)

Answer (score 0):

> Application is developed in VS 2010, WPF

Irrelevant.

> The version of SQL Server in use does not support datatype 'datetime2'

Well, it is quite exact in what it says, is is not? You use something in sql level with the datetime2 data type, the sql server version the client uses does not support that. Reason is- that is not an old data type, so old sql versions do not support it.

Simple like that.

Your fault.

Likely you have not specified a proper version as required so the client runs on a very old version of sql server.

Or the clients fault.

Tell him to upgrade or change your programming to use an older data type.